# Download PDFs with incomplete URLs in HTML with Beautiful Soup/Requests

Tags: python, pdf, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-requests-html

I want to download all 259 the PDFs listed on the page https://www.mdpi.com/search?authors=University+of+Alabama%2C+Tuscaloosa, e.g.:

```
<a href="/1424-8220/21/19/6384/pdf" class="UD_Listings_ArticlePDF" onclick="if (!window.__cfRLUnblockHandlers) return false; ga('send', 'pageview', '/1424-8220/21/19/6384/pdf');" title="Article PDF" data-cf-modified-fa685c2bcda960230d46973e-="">
<i class="material-icons">get_app</i>
</a>
```

The href only has the part of the URL after the domain, so the full URL is https://mdpi.com/1424-8220/21/19/6384/pdf.

When I run this to download the file:

```
for link in links:
    if ('/pdf' in link.get('href', [])):
        i += 1
        print("Downloading file: ", i)
        response = requests.get(link.get('href'))
```

I get this traceback:

```
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '/1424-8220/21/19/6384/pdf': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http:///1424-8220/21/19/6384/pdf?
```

Where do I put the missing part of the URL, "https://mdpi.com"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.get()` is accepting a string, so f-string should work.

```
for link in links:
    if ('/pdf' in link.get('href', [])):
        i += 1
        print("Downloading file: ", i)
        response = requests.get(f"https://mdpi.com{link.get('href')}")
```

Comment: Do you know why it only downloaded 15 PDFs? The search results here show 259. https://www.mdpi.com/search?authors=University+of+Alabama%2C+Tuscaloosa

Comment: well, first of all - your only `if` says that all links with `/pdf`, so maybe only 15 links has this `/pdf`? Second thing - there is a limit of 50 results for page, you wouldn't be able to download 259 anyway. You'd have to iterate tru the paging.

Comment: @BrianC. Maybe this can help you getting better results if the class name is still the same. `results = soup.find_all(attrs={"class": re.compile(r"^UD_Listings_ArticlePDF$", re.I)})`

Comment: Thanks, I'm still getting 15 results at a time. I'm confused because I would expect to find 50 pdfs referenced when looking at view page source, but it's always 15 regardless of the number of results per page I set.

Comment: try to show more code, maybe we can find the problem. Are you getting some kind of error? Or you have 15 items in `links` list?

Comment: I edited the post with all the code. I tried replacing the URL with https://www.mdpi.com/search?sort=pubdate&page_count=200&year_from=1996&year_to=2021&authors=University+of+Alabama%2C+Tuscaloosa&view=default, but there were still 15 items in the links list. I also tried your suggestion and got 15 results, no errors.

Comment: I feel like you might need to use selenium. I checked the page myself and you can probably see that there is a lot of content generated after the initial request. And that is probably causing the issue.